# JQuery "Boostrap Confirmation" plugin doesn't show in second click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

When I click a second time the confirmation box does not show, it stopped working when I changed the confirmation from a MVC Action (redirect) to an Ajax method.

Maybe the reason is because I don't refresh the page anymore. How can I solve it? Resetting the BootStrap.Confirmation variable?

```
// Submit (Approve, Disaprove, SetPending, SetBilled)
$('#divSetStatus button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Check if there is an item selected
    var totalSelected = TableManaged.GetSelectedRowsTotal($('#datatableList'));
    if (totalSelected > 0) {

        // select button pressed
        var newStatus = e.target.value;
        var button = $('button[value=' + newStatus + ']');
        var selectedRows = TableManaged.GetSelectedRowsIds($('#datatableList')).toString();

        // initialize Bootstrap.Confirmation plugin
        button.confirmation({
            singleton: true,
            popout: true,
            onConfirm: function () {

                // Set Status
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: baseUrl + "TimeSheetManagement/SetStatus",
                    data: {
                        screen: $('#hdnScreen').val(),
                        status: newStatus,
                        ids: selectedRows
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        // do something
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // Asks for a confirmation
        button.confirmation('show');

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. It happend because I've used

```
$('#divSetStatus button').confirmation('show');
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('#divSetStatus button').confirmation(); });
```

button.confirmation() will show the confirmation dialog only after button is clicked, however it'll work for the subsequent clicks as well.

Comment: Hi I tried it, and with .confirmation(), now it is in the first click that doesn't work haha. Can you give me an example of your code? thanks

Comment: I think it's because you bind it with the click event. You should remove it from there and do something like `$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#divSetStatus button').confirmation();
});` instead.

Comment: The problem is how am I going to set the parameters in this case? I check if there is any item selected in the grid, also I get values from some fields on screen.

Comment: Try to use javascript's `.click()` method on your #divSetStatus button to activate it programtically whenever you want to show the confirmation.